# Grep Substring and Print Complete String only along with filename

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have data in below format  in multiple files

```
file1  123 dhhdha hkhdkhld ABC123.khdllajld
file2 48-385-83 ABC456.7070 
file3 CYX hdlhlahl gdiad
file4 lddf ABC456.12345
```

I am trying to get all filename and the complete string ( not line ) which contains ABC . I tried using grep but it not printing the complete string  but only substring.

```
grep -rniol '/path' -e 'ABC_'
```

I want the output as :--

```
file1 ABC123
file2 ABC456
file4 ABC456
```

Can someone help me with same ?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rseaman@Ubuntu-PC:~/temp/20180310/49211913$ echo "123 dhhdha hkhdkhld ABC123.khdllajld" > file1
rseaman@Ubuntu-PC:~/temp/20180310/49211913$ echo "48-385-83 ABC456.7070" > file2
rseaman@Ubuntu-PC:~/temp/20180310/49211913$ grep -rHoE 'ABC[^. ]*' *
file1:ABC123
file2:ABC456
```

The `-H` forces the filename to be printed.

The `-E` uses Extended Regex.

The `-o` is used to get only the regex pattern returned.

`'ABC[^. ]*'` = Only get `ABC` followed by any characters that is not a space or `.`.

And if you really wanted it in the exact format, you can replace the `:` with a space: `grep -rHoE 'ABC[^. ]*' * | tr ':' ' '`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `o` from `-rniol` as it stands for "Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of matching lines" ([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)).

Comment: That would print whole line . I want only the string which contains the greped word as substring,

Comment: By "string" you mean the "word"? If so what would you define as a word separator? You can edit your original question to specify expected output.